# error: bitmap configuration android

Tags: android, bitmap

> I have tried to find a solution but all efforts were futile, the main reason is to create Bitmap and then use it to draw a text, like on iphone music app if there is no embedded picture in audiofile, like:
>   [enter link description here](http://core0.staticworld.net/images/article/2014/02/artwork-missing-100246932-medium.png)

```
public static Bitmap drawText(String text, int textWidth, int textSize, int width, int height) {
    // Get text dimensions
    TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
            | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
    textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint,
            textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

    // Create bitmap and canvas to draw to
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, RGB_565);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

    // Draw background
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
            | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    c.drawPaint(paint);

    // Draw text
    c.save();
    c.translate(0, 0);
    mTextLayout.draw(c);
    c.restore();

    return b;
}
```

> *Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, RGB_565);*
>   launches a fatal exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.a1.musicplayer, PID: 2253
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown bitmap configuration
                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:856)
                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:823)
                  at com.example.a1.musicplayer.SongAdapter.drawText(SongAdapter.java:116)
                  at com.example.a1.musicplayer.SongAdapter.getView(SongAdapter.java:84)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2360)
                  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1972)
                  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
                  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
                  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1744)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2161)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at
```

> i have tried all configurations but result is the same.

Comment: What's your value for *width* and *height*? And can you also show the import statement for RGB_565?

Comment: import static android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

Comment: imageView.getMaxWidth(), imageView.getMaxHeight()

Comment: import android.widget.ImageView;

Comment: getMaxWidth() and getMaxHeight() probably return something like LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, which is -1. This is the invalid configuration.

Comment: Log.d("TAG IMAGE VIEW", "imageView max width " + imageView.getMaxWidth() + "imageView max height " + imageView.getMaxHeight());

Comment: D/TAG IMAGE VIEW: imageView max width 2147483647imageView max height 2147483647